# Joomla 2.5 get all Ids of subcategories and do subselect in query

Tags: templates, joomla, subquery

I rack my brain with two hard nuts. 
Thus the problems are linked together I post them in one thread. Unfortunately I am not able to provide a Test Example. Here we go …

I use following Query in my Joomla 2.5 template:

```
->select(array('a.description','a.display_name','a.parent_id','a.filename','a.url', 'b.title','b.alias', 'b.id','b.catid','b.state','c.title as catTitle','c.parent_id as catparent'))
->from('#__attachments AS a')
->join('LEFT', '#__content AS b ON (a.parent_id = b.id)')
->join('INNER', '#__categories AS c ON b.catid = c.id')
->where("b.state = 1 AND c.parent_id in (23)");
```

this joins me the module table "#_*attachments" with "#*_content" and "#_articles". with the goal to get the attached images of an article, the title of  the article, the alias, the article id, the category title, the category id,...

### My Questions

1. The query gives me the id of the parent category ('c.parent_id as catparent') of the category from the article. Is it possible to have a subselect which also gives me the title of this parent-category (the id is in catparent)?
2. Thus I only want articles from special subcategories I have an "in"n in my where.  know all subcategories are childs of parent category with id (5). How do I get all Id´s of the subcategories from cat 5. So I can use this Id´s in my "b.state = 1 AND c.parent_id in  ($allSubCategoryIDs)" where clause?

Kind regards,

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ad 1.**

To fetch the title of the parent category, add

```
->select('parent.title AS parentTitle')
->join('left', '#__categories AS parent ON parent.id=c.parent_id')
```

to your query.

**ad 2.**

Since Joomla stores categories as Nested Sets, this is accomplished by changing

```
->where("b.state = 1 AND c.parent_id in (23)");
```

into

```
->where('b.state=1')
->where('c.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt')
```