# Get all subcategories counter of category by query in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i want to get count of `subcategories` of main category in template index file.
`category id` will be show during `com_content` blog layout call

how can i run query to get count of subcategories of main category

i have tried following code but still not success

[tried code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708179/joomla-2-5-get-all-ids-of-subcategories-and-do-subselect-in-query)

Comment: Sounds to me like you are going about this the wrong way. Have you created a custom component or module for this?

Comment: The part about "in template index file" doesn't make sense to me.  Sounds like you might just need to use the categories module.

Comment: @Elin @ Søren Beck Jensen  i want to hide one module if com_content category view have sub categories,i can put this condition in joomla template index file


so i want to put condition if particular category have sub category or not

Comment: If this is a module you made yourself code that condidtion it in the module itself.  If you want to know if a category has subcategories, first this is already known since the option to display that or not is available in the blog layout, but you can also for the category data look at the values of `lft` and `rgt` and see if the difference between them is greater than 1.  If you need the exact number take the difference and divide by 2.  Or use the JTableNested API which will give you some of that.